# Time Series Structural Break and ADF Test

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, acf-pacf

i have a time series variable which i checked it for stationarity using ADF test and arima proc in SAS

proc arima data=&td19;
identify var=interest_rate stationarity=(adf=4);
run;
quit;

Below is the ADF test and trend & correlation analysis

i started from the table from the bottom (trend model) and using the Tau compared it with 5% until to reject the null. i concluded that the series is stationary since 0.0315<0.05 zero mean model

However, when i see the ACF/PACF, based on my understanding, the series in not stationary. This is because the ACF decays slowly

My questions are : is this series stationary or not?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi: Any acf plot in the arima framework is going to assume that the process has a constant long term mean ( unless the series needs differencing ).  your series doesn't have one due to that sharp drop in the middle of it which makes the acf plot not useful.

Comment: thanks for your response. I guess that you mean that i can conclude that the series is stationary using the Tau statistic, is this correct?

Comment: I think that the structural break that interrupts the series at about time 40 is an important feature to take into consideration. For instance, ADF test does not work well when there is a structural break (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211140/autoregressive-model-for-time-series-with-structural-breaks))

Comment: hi, thanks for this. Yes, it seems that there is a structural break in the series that i didn't take in consideration.

Comment: Hi: I don't know if you can conclude that it's stationary but, because of the structural break ( thanks to N9N9 for the use of the term structural break. It's a  better term than I used in my first comment ), , the use of the acf for identification of stationarity is not correct. I'm not sure of whether there are tests for stationarity in the case where there are structural breaks. Maybe the link that N9N9 provided will say something about that.

Comment: hi, thanks again, this is very useful. I had a look in the link provided by N9N9. Just a question,  could i rely on Tau statistic for the stationarity test or it is also not reliable due to the structural break of the series?